# Sub menu drop down in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, navigation

I have hidden my sub menu, and added css to show the sub menu drop down when hovering over the parent menu item.

What I would like to do is have the sub menu drop down when the parent menu button is "clicked" instead of when it is "hovered" over.

My css is:

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.shiftnav ul li:hover > ul {

display: block; /* show sub menus when hovering over a parent */

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I Made and Example 
Here is HTML Codes:**

```css
#demo {
  margin: 30px 0 50px 0;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#demo .wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
#demo .parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  color: #282D31;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: border-radius .1s linear, background .1s linear, z-index 0s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .8s;
  text-align: center;
}
#demo .parent:hover,
#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0s;
}
#demo .content:hover ~ .parent {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
#demo .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 0;
  width: 180px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: height .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .4s;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
#demo .wrapper:active .content {
  height: 123px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
#demo .content:hover {
  height: 123px;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
#demo .content ul {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
#demo .content ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#demo .content li:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
}
#demo .content li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #888;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#demo .content li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Consectetur adipisicing</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Reprehenderit</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Commodo consequat</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">Drop Down Parent 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <ul>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Consectetur adipisicing</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Reprehenderit</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>Commodo consequat</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">Drop Down Parent 2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you so much.  I am having difficult implementing your example to my menu.  I have tried:

`.shiftnav-nav .shiftnav-target {

   display: block; 

}`
"shiftnav-target being the partent"

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve nearly the same thing with `li a:first-child:nth-last-child(x) { }`.

Here is a [quick example](https://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/). The markup is just your standard nested UL, but note that I have only used one class in the HTML, on the root `<ul>`. Test this out yourself, add any number of nested lists at any level!

Comment: thank you for that.   I am having difficulty using the example in my menu.  I have tried changing my css to :
`.shiftnav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(x) {

display: block; 

}~